# How to generate a void method in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, when I type `main` <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, it will generate a `static void main` method for me. And when I type `methodName` <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, smart code completion will suggest generating the method named `methodName`.

How can I auto-generate a **void method** in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

To create a new method from usage in the code like:

```
...
someMethodName()
...
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> on the red code:

[image: Create Method]

It's also possible to type `void methodName()` and use **Complete Statement** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>), it will become:

```
void methodName() {
    |
}
```

You *could* create your own [Live Template](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/live-templates.html) as @Makoto answered, but programming by intention seems to be more natural. When you don't have a method, you write code that will use it, then create the method from the intention action - this way IDEA will generate the method signature automatically according to the parameters and return type in the not yet existing method usage, like `String result = someMethod(stringParam);`.

Finally, it is worth nothing that in IntelliJ IDEA `main()` method can be generated using `psvm`<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Hi, i type methodName() ALT+Enter, but it didn't pop create method dialog.My idea version is 11.1.3

Comment: Does the code become red? Note that you need to type it in the place where it will be called from, for example in the body of another method. If you type it directly in the class, where method call would be invalid, intention will not work. It's designed to create a new method from its usage. If you want to generate a new method inside the class and not from usage, use the Live Templates approach or Complete Statement as described in my answer.

Comment: I guess, psvm = public static void main

Comment: Works like a charm on **IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.6**

Comment: How can i customize this creation template of someMethodName() ?

Comment: psvm + TAB are OP

Answer (score 53):

### IntelliJ IDEA 15

#### Generate a `main` method

- Default:

  Type `psvm` (**p**ublic **s**tatic **v**oid **m**ain) > press <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Use the template from Eclipse (`main` instead of `psvm`)

  - **File** > **Settings** or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

    [image: File > Settings]
  - **Editor** > **Live Templates**

    [image: Editor Live Templates]
  - From the right side, click on the "**+**" sign > **Live Template**

    [image: Add > Live Template]
  - Add the following details:

    - Abbreviation: `main`
    - Description: `main() method declaration`
    - Template text:

      ```
      public static void main(String[] args){
        $END$
      }
      ```

      [image: main]

      You will see the new template added in Others.
  - Click on **Define**

    [image: Define]
  - Select **Java** > Press on **OK**

    [image: Select Java]
  - Type `main` in your Java code > press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

#### Generate a `void` method

- Type your **method name** followed by parentheses (+ the arguments, if you use them) - E.g.: `m()` or `m(1,2)` > Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> > Click on "Create method ..." (or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> if it is already selected)

  [image: New method]

Comment: This answer answered the question, with a nice explanation.

Answer (score 42):

1. Type the abbreviation of the main() method template:
   [image]
2. Press the template invocation key. By default, it is Tab. The abbreviation expands to the main() method.

Comment: This only explicitly generates the `main` method, not a general-purpose `void` method.

Comment: Yes, but you can rename method and change method signature.

Answer (score 11):

IntelliJ makes use of [Live Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/live-templates.html) to do its code completion.  It's then a matter of deciding what shorthand name you wish to use to name your void method.

Here's an example.  Create a live template in Settings > Live Templates, then select the "Other" box.   Hit the + on the right, then give your template a shorthand keystroke name.

Here's the one that I typed up.  With the two different variables `$NAME$` and `$ARGS$`, I can tab between them when I need to fill them in.  `$END$` is where the cursor ends when I'm done tabbing through the other two variables.

```
void $NAME$ ($ARGS$) {
    $END$
}
```

The shorthand name I used is `pmeth`.  So, every time I type `pmeth` into IntelliJ in a Java file, then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, this method is filled in, and my cursor automatically starts at `$NAME$`.

Comment: I use your advice now to generate new method by using "fun" abbreviation.
It is really nice!
`public $T$ $MN$($PT$ $PN$) {
    $END$
}`

Answer (score 6):

Just type main and a suggestion will pop up. Press enter.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

type `psvm` on the Java class and then Cntrl+Period key

Comment: This only explicitly generates the `main` method, not a general-purpose `void` method.

Answer (score 2):

Simply Type the abbreviation of the main() method template:

`psvm then Enter`

Comment: This only explicitly generates the `main` method, not a general-purpose `void` method.

Comment: @Jimmy:  That is colloquially referred to as "the `main` method".  It is ***not*** by any stretch of the imagination a "generic" or general purpose `void` method.

Comment: @Makoto My mistake.