# IntelliJ not creating method on unknown usage

Tags: java, intellij-idea

On IntelliJ 12, contrary to what is said on [1], upon writing a method name that is not yet defined on its usage location, is not bringing any popup.

In the example below, for instance, given an already existing class SomeClass, I would expect IntelliJ, after writing "notYetDefinedMethod", to offer me to create a static void method on SomeClass, which does not happen.

```
    void foo () {
        SomeClass.notYetDefinedMethod ();
    }
```

This is the same behavior observed by user lichengwu (on answer from CrazyCoder) in question [2], but there it seems to be still unanswered.

How to achieve the behavior mentioned in [1]?

[1] http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_generation.html#link11

[2] [How to generate a void method in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543977/how-to-generate-a-void-method-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: This behavior is working exactly as advertised for me in Intellij IDEA 12.0.1.

Comment: After further research I found this issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97685 which actually related to my problem and solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further research I discovered that an issue [1] with the Coffeescript plugin can cause intentions not be shown. In sum, I disabled the Coffeescript plugin and the now I have again intentions and such completions.

[1] http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97685